# for $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$, finding the derivative of $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^\infty f(x+t)\cdot xdx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$,
>
> (a) Prove that
> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_0^\infty f(x+t)\cdot x\mathbb{d}x=-\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
> (b) Prove that
> $$ \iint_{(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)}f(x+y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\infty f(x)\cdot x\mathrm{d}x$$

I'm actually really lost on both sections without much clue where to start, so sorry about my own attempt being short, but for (a), I've tried differentiating under the integral sign, which got me nowhere, and for (b) I've tried using (a) and saying that:

$$ \iint_{(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)}f(x+y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f_y(x)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$
$$ = \int_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}f_y(x)\cdot x\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = -\int_0^\infty x\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}f_y(x)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$

where I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: For the second, let $u = x+y, v = x$, so one of the integrations is done along constant $x+y$.

Comment: @martycohen I don't think doing this is correct in general. Consider $\int_0^1\int_0^11dxdy$ compared to $\int_0^21dx$. It might be justifiable in the case of $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$, but I am not sure how to justify it..

Answer (score 1):

I proceed very naively
on the first question,
since that's the math I know.

If
$g(t)
=\int_0^\infty f(x+t)xdx
$,

$\begin{array}\\
g(t+h)-g(t)
&=\int_0^\infty f(x+t+h)x\,dx-\int_0^\infty f(x+t)x\, dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty (f(x+t+h)-f(x+t))\, x\,dx\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}
&=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{f(x+t+h)-f(x+t)}{h}x\,dx\\
\text{so}\\
\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{f(x+t+h)-f(x+t)}{h}x\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+t+h)-f(x+t)}{h}x\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty f'(x+t)x\,dx\\
&=(xf(x))|_0^{\infty}-\int_0^\infty f(x+t)dx
\qquad\text{(integrating by parts)}\\
&=-\int_0^\infty f(x+t)dx
\qquad\text{(assuming }\lim_{x \to \infty} x\, f(x) = 0)\\
\end{array}
$

I'll leave all the justifications
for the taking of limits
and reversing limit and integration
to those more knowledgable.
Of course,
that is probably the point
of the question.

Comment: But $f'$ need not exist.

Comment: @Siminore It does. I'm sorry I messed up, it's $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ and not  $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: @martycohen does $\lim_x\to\infty xf(x)=0$ necessarily follows from $f(x)$ being integrable on $(0,\infty)$? Differentiating under the integral pretty much got me to $\int_0^\infty f'(x+t)\cdot xdx$ where I wasn't sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why are we able to pass the limit through the integral on this step? $\lim_{h \to 0}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{f(x+t+h)-f(x+t)}{h}x\,dx = \int_0^\infty\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+t+h)-f(x+t)}{h}x\,dx $

Comment: As I said, I did this quite naively, assuming everything I needed to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it,
here is a proof of
the discrete version of
$\iint_{(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)}f(x+y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\infty f(x)\cdot x\mathrm{d}x
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a(i+j)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n}a(n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)\sum_{j=0}^{n}1\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a(n)\\
\end{array}
$